# Limit the number of results on a ASP.NET ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, listview, collections

I have a ListView bound to a Generic List collection.

I need to be able to limit the number of items bound to something like 5, and show a more button in the template.

I can handle the DataBinding event, and remove the last few items in the List<>, but something about that doesn't feel right.  I also can't limit the list to 5 beforehand, because I need to know that there are more than 5, to show the "more" button.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databind the list to

```
yourlist.Take(5);
```

(i.e. the LINQ operator), but perform the check for the more button based on the original list.